# Rolling total not calculating properly in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to put together a rolling monthly total measure in PowerBI but my measure is not even calculating

My data is similar to below

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyfBM.png)
[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDZMK.png)

**I have made my calculation as follows:-**

```
Rolling Annualized Revenue = 
                            CALCULATE(
                                [Annual Revenue], 
                              FILTER('Calendar Lookup', 
                                     'Calendar Lookup'[Date]
                                   <=MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date])))
```

Edit: I just realized I copied the wrong formula altogether here
For whatever this is not working at all and yields just the annual revenue not a rolling sum

[Calc Result in a matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po1tH.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand?

Comment: I did not realize you there was a way to mark and answer as solved. I just went through and did that. Thanks, maybe next time you can be more direct in what was being done instead of alluding to an issue

Comment: Please explain what kind of a "rolling sum" you're after, e.g. what's the rolling window? Your formula rather looks like a "running total".

Comment: @Peter So after thinking over the weekend I realized I should use the customer lifetime value of 12 months instead.

I think something might actually be wrong with how PowerBI is treating my Calendar table and I am unsure how to fix it. I tried the following.

`
Rolling 12 Month Annual Revenue = 
                            CALCULATE([Annual Revenue], 
                            DATESINPERIOD('Calendar Lookup'[Date], 
                            MAX('Calendar Lookup'[Date]),-12,MONTH))
`
https://imgur.com/a/7PNDeVQ

If I mark my calendar table as my date table it works kind of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that I needed to add the year to the row context in order for my calculation to work properly.